Block Editor - Wordpress 6.1 - CPT Archive Issue - While the title changes in the loop, all records display the same data
I am using the block editor with CPT.  I have a loop that iterates though my CPT.  The title changes for each record but not the data in the CPT.  I am using a shortcode to display my custom post type data.  Will I need to pass the post id to the short code?  How can I get CPT data in an archive loop please?
function fs_ski_resort_field_fn($attr){
    $key = shortcode_atts(array(
        'key' => ''
        ), $attr);
        // get the acf key
        $the_value_of_fs_field = get_acf_key($key['key']);
        return $the_value_of_fs_field;
}

add_shortcode('fs_ski_resort_field', 'fs_ski_resort_field_fn');
function get_acf_key($key){

$fs_ski_resort_data = get_field('field_64b38c4e3ec56', $post_id ); 

switch ($key) {
       case 'name':                    
          $result = $fs_ski_resort_data['fs_name'] ?: $fs_ski_resort_data['osm_name']; 
          break;
}
return $result;

}
I then call the shortcode in
[fs_ski_resort_field key="name"]​

Above shortcode is in:  archive-fs_ski_resorts.html
I have about 300 records.  "name" repeats the first record's name 300x.

Post your existing code. Nobody here is psychic, and fixing an error is much less work than rewriting it from scratch for you.

Thanks and have added some code.

We're going to need to see fs_ski_resort_field_fn() too. All we can see there is the hook to it (which tells us nothing) and a completely different function called get_acf_key() with no context on how that's being called.

Sorry, forgot to add one function call.  Added.

$post_id is undefined in your function. That cannot work.

That was me playing with the function.  Tried it with $post_id = NULL and same thing,  That is what my initial question was though - do i need to pass the post_id?  I though that if in the loop it should automatically be there.

That would be a question for the ACF support, here third party code is off topic.

Not sure why that would be ACF specific.   The meta data is held in a table like other data.  Wondering if custom post type data fields have to be given a post_id even if I use;  get_post_meta();

The shortcode is not executed within the Query Loop Block.  The loop is executed by the containing page.  This explains why the custom post type data appears repeatedly.  This explains how to extend it I think;  https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/extending-the-query-loop-block/ Wow, what a massive undertaking to show custom post types in an archive.
